# How to print a specific number of values per line using Arrays.toString?

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I print my array like this:

```
public void something () {
    String out = (java.util.Arrays.toString(array)+(...));
    showMessageDialog(null, out);
```

Main calls on another method in a class containing this method. 
I want to have a line break for every 8 values of my array. I know I could do it like this if I printed every value in a for loop:

```
if (printed == 8) {
           System.out.print("\n");
           printed = 0;
```

But how to do so when using Arrays.toString()?
 Thanks for any help!

Comment: It can't be done. Arrays.toString always returns a string without any line separators.

Comment: If you are lucky, showMessageDialog() will accept HTML for the string in `out` - so you could put a little HTML wrapper around your list string, and the HTML renderer will format it across multiple lines - though probably not the way you want it to :-(.

Comment: *"how to do so when using Arrays.toString()"* You don't. You do what you said yourself: *I could do it like this if I printed every value in a for loop*. So write such a loop, but build a string instead of printing.

Comment: So you want to override the behavior of `Arrays.toString`? Then you need to use the magic of reflection *or* use a mocking framework. But why do you want this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `java.lang.Instrumentation` to change the method's behavior at runtime via a debugging agent. See for example: https://github.com/turn/RedefineClassAgent

Answer (score 0):

As stated `Arrays.toString` wont be the right choice for you, but you can create the string using Java streams in more or less compact manner.

```
    String result = java.util.stream.IntStream
            .range(0, array.length)
            .mapToObj( i -> array[i] + ( ( (i + 1) %8 ) == 0 ? "\n":", " ) )
            .collect( Collectors.joining("") );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + (i % 7 == 0 && i > 0 ? "\n" : ""));
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

It is possible, but not worth it.

You can wrie a class extending Array. Then you need to override toString() method and implement it as you wish. But to use your implementation of toString(), all arrays need to be objects of your new class. Then every System.out.println() will use your implementation.

It is possible, but totally not worth it. It is a great waste of your and CPU time.

Comment: Which Array class would you suggest to override? java.lang.reflect.Array is final

Comment: Arrays aren't classes in the normal sense, they're implemented by the JVM. You can't extend them.

Comment: I didn't know it is final, my fault.